# How do I split a string in regex by a single S or E char followed by digits in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like the following.

```
ids = 'S1486S1485E444'
```

I want to split it into an array of parts separated by the S or E like the following.

```
["S1486", "S1485", "E444"]
```

This is what I came up with but it gives the undefined and empty strings as well.

```
ids.split(/(S+\d+)|(E+\d+)/)

["", "S1486", undefined, "", "S1485", undefined, "", undefined, "E444", ""]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or just do a match:

```
'S1486S1485E444'.match(/([SE]+\d*)/g)
```

Comment: This one actually works best for me as it it more strict on the char + digits. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use a *[lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)* to split on the character boundary where an **S** or **E** is the next character:

```
var ids = 'S1486S1485E444';

var result = ids.split(/(?=S|E)/); // S1486,S1485,E444
```

The reason this works is that while `.split` normally removes the character it matches on, this doesn't match on a character itself but a spot where the *next* character is the one you want.

Comment: Thanks, I like how I don't need to add in the filter method or ignore empties with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `.split()` is the separator by which you want to divide your string. If that regex contains matching groups (denoted by parenthesis) then they are also included in the result.

One way would be similar to what you have, but then filter out all the empty strings.

```
ids.split(/([SE]\d+)/).filter(Boolean);

// result: ["S1486", "S1485", "E444"]
```

---

If your target browsers don't have `.filter` on the Array prototype, you'll have to implement that for yourself, sorry. Alternatively, just get every second value from the result:

```
ids.split(/([SE]\d+)/)

// result: ["", "S1486", "", "S1485", "", "E444", ""]
```

From there, a simple `for` loop could get you the parts you're after.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [`.match()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) it will return an array containing all matches:

```
ids.match(/(S\d+|E\d+)/g)
// OR
ids.match(/([SE]\d+)/g)
```

Note that I've tweaked the regex a little and you need the `g` flag for `.match()` to return an array. If there are no matches it returns `null`.